# See sparql with specific information

Tags: sparql

I want to visualize everything (well **not all** only those attributes) concerning the area to be called, without the filter all are displayed and even information that I do not consider relevant, so I only want to see those attributes (predicates).
It's not even hard for me to understand sparql and I have to show results now !! so thanks in advance

Query

```
PREFIX dco: <http://192.168.1.10:8890/task/ontology/>
PREFIX dcr: <http://192.168.1.10:8890/digcomp/resource/>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
select * where {
    ?Sujeto ?Predicado ?Objeto .
    ?Sujeto rdf:type dco:Areas .
    FILTER (?Objeto="Information and data literacy")
}
```

Result

```
| Subject        | Predicate           | Object  |
| ------------- |:-------------:| -----:|
| dcr:areas/1 | rdfs:label | "Information and data literacy" |
```

Desired result

```
| Subject        | Predicate           | Object  |
| ------------- |:-------------:| -----:|
| dcr:areas/1      | rdf:type | dco:Areas |
| dcr:areas/1 | rdfs:label | "Information and data literacy" |
| dcr:areas/1 | dcr:name_area | "Information and data literacy"|
```

Comment: SELECT * WHERE {?s ?p ?o {SELECT ?s WHERE {?s a dco:Areas ; ?p ?o . FILTER(?o = "Information and data literacy")}}}
This is called a 'nested query'.

Comment: go thanks how it works "a" in clause **where**

Comment: a is short for rdf:type. They mean exactly the same, but a is shorter.